# Remove virus- Vista Security 2011

Tags: virus-removal

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Computer is infected by a virus or a malware, what do I do now?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware-what-do-i-do-now)

This seems to be a virus that has infected my computer. Are there any free, trustworthy programs that I can use to get rid of it? If not, how do I get rid of it manually?

Comment: How can you tell it's infected? What are the symptoms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [Spyware Doctor with Antivirus](http://www.pctools.com/spyware-doctor-antivirus/?ref=google_spyware-doctor_en&gclid=CKTKwsryvacCFRNrgwodi22RAg). It received top scores in previous years for real time virus killin' action and zero day threats. You can try the free version, and let it run for a while. It'll kill your viruses, but it'll take its own time, even though it won't tell you. Be sure to run an IntelliScan, first.

If you want pure scanners, you should try [MalwareBytes](http://malwarebytes.org/), and [Trend Micro HouseCall](http://housecall.trendmicro.com/).

A good combination of scanners/real time protection can get rid of most malware.

If you want specialized help, but can wait a few days, they've got experts over at the [BleepingComputer](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/) [Forums](http://www.bleepingcomputer.com/forums/).

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

I use [**Avast Free**](http://www.avast.com/free-antivirus-download), which has never had an issue.

I also use [**McAfee Stinger**](http://www.mcafee.com/us/downloads/free-tools/stinger.aspx) as a secondary, specific (and small file size) tool.

Answer (score 1):

Follow the order given below to disinfect your PC

1.) On a PC that is Not infected, Make a boot AV disc then boot from the disc on the Infected PC and scan the hard drive, remove any infections it finds, I prefer the Kaspersky disc myself. The New 2010 Kaspersky disc can update the AV dat files if you are connected to the internet at the time of scan and is suggested to update before the scan.

http://www.techmixer.com/free-bootable-antivirus-rescue-cds-download-list/

2.) Then:
Install free MBAM, run the program and go to the Update tab and update it, then go to the Scanner Tab and do a quick scan, select and remove anything it finds.

http://download.cnet.com/Malwarebytes-Anti-Malware/3000-8022_4-10804572.html

3.) When MBAM is done install SAS free version, run a quick scan, remove what it automatically selects.
http://www.superantispyware.com/download.html

These last 2 are not AV softwares like Norton, they are on demand scanners that only scan for nasties when you run the program and will not interfere with your installed AV, these can be run once a day or week to ensure you are not infected. Be sure you update them before each daily-weekly scan.

Comment: I'm missing point 4.) - updating the system and 5.) not working as privileged user. Otherwise I would have given a +1 ;)